# Question about my site layout, DIV inside another DIV is centering

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a site layout.
This is my html code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#A {
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#B {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#C {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
}

#D {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  Header
</div>
<div id="B">
  Main
  <div id="C">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
<div id="D">
  De footer
</div>
```

So now if I open the site up, div C is inside div B like it's supposed to.
But like the text "Main" div C is not at the top of div B.
Its supposed to be just as big fitting perfectly inside of div B.
I'm wondering if anyone has a quick fix for this? Or is my padding wrong...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#A{
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#B{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#C{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#D{
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
   Header
</div>
<div id="B">
  Main
  <div id="C">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
<div id="D">
  De footer
</div>
```

I hope that works for you. You need to change the #B **position: relative** and then you can position the inner #C **absolute**. **top: 0** and **left: 0**.
If I understood your problem correctly, this looks should help you.

Comment: Thanks! At least now it fits, the sizes aren't perfect but i'll fix that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you just want to fit the *Nav div* on top of the *Main div*?

For that you have to make the *Main div* **relative** and add

```
top: 0;
```

to the *Nav div*.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#A {
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#B {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

#C {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0px;
}

#D {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  Header
</div>
<div id="B">
  Main
  <div id="C">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
<div id="D">
  De footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a stable `layout`, it is not good idea to make `#C` as `position: absolute;` because it has some side-effects. 
and its good to change it's `display` to `inline-block`, then it works.